# How to logoff from a SharePoint 2010 site using a c# client?

Tags: c#, windows, cookies, sharepoint-2010

I found this [Remote Authentication in SharePoint Client Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh147177(v=office.14).aspx) which has examples to popup a IE window in order to get all the cookies for remote SharePoint access.  Ideally, the program popups a window to the site, asks the user to login, and then disappears.  The program then can insert items into the SharePoint site.

### Problem Description

I observed that this example application pops up a window but redirected to our company's example SharePoint site, instead of my site, and it didn't ask me to log in.  Then if I close this window manually the clientContext (from `ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl)`) in the example code will be null pointer.  To fix this, I first manually open an IE window, go to my site, I will be automatically logged in (which I think that's the problem since the example application wasn't able to get a cookie because there was no logging in), then if I manually log off from the IE window, run the example application, it will pop up a window, seems it automatically log in and then the window disappeared and the items can be added to the list.

### My Question

Is there a way to programmatically log off the SharePoint site from the application at first?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in authorization cookie. You must delete FedAuth cookie to "logout".